# static method invoked via derived type

Tags: c#, sharpdevelop

There is a class, called circle. It contains circleID, circleGeometry and circlePath propertities.

```
public class Circle 
{
    public string ID {get; set;}
    public EllipseGeometry circleGeometry {get; set;}
    public Path circlePath {get; set;}
}
```

Now, I'm trying to set ZIndex value for a circle. For example it'll be 2.

```
Canvas.SetZIndex(someCircleID.circlePath,2);
```

But I have such kind of warning:

> "static method invoked via derived type"

Can somebody explain me what does that mean?

Comment: At a guess, `Canvas` is a subtype of another type and `SetZIndex` is defined by the latter; not by `Canvas`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`SetZIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.setzindex(v=vs.110).aspx) is defined on the `Panel` class, which `Canvas` derives from. The compiler is generating a warning saying you're using a static method on a sub-type. This isn't an actual *problem*, but it may lead to confusions when used in certain ways. As `SetZIndex` is void returning, that shouldn't be a problem.

But imagine the following:

```
var ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create("ftp://my.ftp.com");
```

`Create` is actually a static method of `WebRequest`, but is used on `HttpWebRequest` instead, because it is a derived-type and you *may* do so. So, you'd expect it to be a web request which is being generated, right? But it isn't, it generates a `FtpWebRequest`, because that's specified in the URI.

**Edit:**

I want to point out that generally, the compiler warnings are there for a reason, that is way this one exists as well. As long as there is no overload of `SetZIndex` created in the `Canvas` class, the call is safe. But as @SriramSakthivel points out in the comments, if any extension method or static method is added to the `Canvas` class (using the `new` modifier) along the way, by you or by anyone else, it will no longer output the desired result and you must be aware of that.

Comment: Downvoted for suggesting warnings aren't a problem. Good advice would be to treat warnings as errors and to fix them.

Comment: @David Nowhere did I attempt to say that all warnings aren't a *problem*. They're there to indicate something may be wrong. In this particular case, the warning may be safely ignored.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov No this warning isn't safe. It could result in serious problem. Refer my answer for details.

Comment: @Sriram That is a hypothetical edge case where adding a static method would be a breaking change to the code. If yoy made that static method, it is your responsibility to make sure you didn't break anything. If it's a framework *breaking change*, it's still your responsibility to make sure nothing breaks.

Comment: If there is a case like that, you can't say "In this particular case, the warning may be safely ignored"

Comment: @SriramSakthivel At the *current point in time*, as there is no such overload of the method, it can be safely ignored. If anything changes in current state, then this is no longer safe. That is what i mean.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I've edited my answer so i'm clear as to what I mean.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Small correction. Overload method isn't a problem, but `new` method is. I mean a method declared with same signature in derived class will cause the problem.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yes, I see what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

This means that the method `SetZIndex` is defined on a base-type of class `Canvas` but you call it using the latter. You´d better be off by using the base-class.